# Sort Clustered column chart in descending order in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Help to sort the chart in decending order means after add 2021 & 2021 value. Max value should come first then second and so on

For ex. Technologyservice delivery should come first

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwyEr.png)